# How to display a toastr alert in a react form after submit succeed or failed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, toastr

I would like to know how to display a toastr alert when clicking the "send information" button showing "Your information has been sent" and if it fails "Your information could not been sent, here is a problem!"

the code i have for sending is:

```
 const sendMail = async (data: FormData) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://us-central1-my-website.cloudfunctions.net/apply-function', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once resolved or rejected, the `response` object will have a property called `status` which indicates whether the request was resolved or rejected by the server (API). You can use the `status` property to show alerts accordingly.

Example

```
import React from 'react';

const Mail = () => {
    const [alert, setAlert] = React.useState({ show: false, message: '' });

    const sendMail = async (data: FormData) => {
        //  It's better to use try catch block when writing an async function.
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://us-central1-my-website.cloudfunctions.net/apply-function',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: data,
                }
            );

            if (response.status === 200) {
                setAlert({
                    show: true,
                    message: 'Your information has been sent!',
                });
            }
        } catch {
            // If response was not successful.
            setAlert({
                show: true,
                message: 'Your information could not be sent!',
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            {/* Other components.. */}
            <Toaster show={alert.show} message={alert.message} />
        </>
    );
};
```